# Menu won't go on top of parallax image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a menu on top of a parallax image however when I add float: left to the ul l{} in CSS it makes the menu go in the parallax image, not on top of it. Need help to make the menu go on top of the parallax image and fixed so that the menu stays above parallax image while scrolling down.

**Here is the HTML for the website:**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Croydon Cycles</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="title">
     <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Croydon Cycles" align="center">

</div>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>

</ul>




<div class="container">



    <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1">
        <div class="b1">
            <a href="shop.html">

                <input type="button" class="button" value="view all bikes" >
            </a>
        </div>




    </div>
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>


</div>


<div class="profiles">

        <p id="Header-1">Here are some of the members of Croydon Cycles:</p>

    <div class="pic-1">
        <img src="images/profile-1.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
        <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
    </div>



    <div class="pic-2">
    <img src="images/profile-2.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular traini.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the CSS code:**

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }


    p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding:0;
    }

   .title {
    text-align: center;
    }

   .container {

    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.parallax {
    background: url('images/background-1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;


}

.b1{
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 45%;
}

.pic-1{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


.pic-2{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;  

}

#Header-1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}

ul {

}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;

}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you didn't clear your floats. So the `ul` basically has a height of 0. Look into using the `clear` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: remove float:left property from ul li selector.

Comment: I am trying to have no whitespace between the list is there any other code that does that apart from float: left;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a div parent for the title and the ul with `headerBlock` class and add the following:

```
.headerBlock {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Like this example

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }


p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding:0;
    }

.title {
    text-align: center;
    }

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.parallax {
    background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/500x500') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;


}

.b1{
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 45%;
}

.pic-1{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


.pic-2{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;  

}

#Header-1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.headerBlock {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Croydon Cycles</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="headerBlock">
<div class="title">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Croydon Cycles" align="center">

</div>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>

</ul>

</div>


<div class="container">



    <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1">
        <div class="b1">
            <a href="shop.html">

                <input type="button" class="button" value="view all bikes" >
            </a>
        </div>




    </div>
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>


</div>


<div class="profiles">

        <p id="Header-1">Here are some of the members of Croydon Cycles:</p>

    <div class="pic-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
        <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
    </div>



    <div class="pic-2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
    <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular traini.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to make the lists have no whitespace between them so I added float: left; to the ul tag it does the job but makes the menu go on the top left side inside the parallax image. I added the code you told me to add when I add the ul tags in order to make my menu is still in the parallax image.

Comment: did you add the headerblock div ? and what do you mean by make the lists have no whitespace between them ?

Comment: yes, I added the headerblock div, when you hover across the list the pointer comes on and off between the gaps of the list, a video on how to create menus showed how to remove this by adding a float: left; to the ul li{} tag when I add this the lists come next to each other with no space but it then goes in the parallax image instead of on top it.

Comment: I have experimented and found out that using the nav tag around the <ul></ul> and your code for the headerblock div, the problem is fixed. Thank you very much for your time on helping me solve this problem.

Comment: Glad i could helped :)